# Eclipse files missing folder, and missing in source

Tags: eclipse, svn, filesystems, missing-data

The repository folder I have been working in changed over night. Files that were in the folder are no longer in it, both in svn and the source folder. The attached pictures show what has changed between the days. The small folder 'kettle' is all that is left from the large one (what it use to look like). It looks like this in windows explorer as well. Also, since I had local changes I had no put to version control yet, I do not want to just re-checkout and lose my changes. Any insight to a solution to getting the original state of my folder would be greatly appreciated.

The current state of the folder:

[image: Shows the current state of the folder]

What the folder looked like yesterday:

[image: Shows what the folder looked like yesterday]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like someone renamed the project folder in the repository. You will need to 
back up your changes (project folder into a zip for example) and try to sort out things manually.

Another solution could be creating your own branch that just mirrors the current state of your workspace. But merging the changes back to trunk might be problematic here, too.